# Odata not applying filters at the SQL level

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, odata

I have a basic Odata end-point that is using Entity Framework to query a database.
When the end point is queried with some basic filters it appears to work properly, however I am noticing a concerning behavior. The following example will demonstrate my concern.

Http GET to:

www.api.com?$filter=SomeField eq (some unique value)

which will lead to the following code:

```
 [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<vwResultObject> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var r db.vwResultObject;
            var b = r.toList<vwResultObject>();
            return r;

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This code works exactly as expected and the return value is the one unique row in the db that matches on the unique field. However my concern is that the list "b"'s length is equal to the total rows in the table. Does this mean that the filters are not applied at the sql level? Am I missing something? It seems very foolish that the filters are not applied to the SQL level and I cannot believe this is what was intended. I must be making a mistake at some point.

Comment: shameless self bump

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?